How to disable Resharper TYPE "Tab to accept" suggestion
I've recently installed ReSharper to my Visual Studio 2022, and when I use the "prop" + tab + tab to create a class property, I can rename the type and the property name normally.
The problem is that whenever I get to write a new line, doesn't matter what I'm writing, Resharper is still "suggesting" me to press "Tab to accept", like this example:
Resharp suggestion
I really don't know what to do about it, I just need to turn off this suggestion, but didn't find anything in the Resharper config.
I've already tried to look at all settings individually in Resharper config, but didn't find any way to disable this "property creation type suggestion".
I've already tried to disable Autopopup from Restsharp's IntelliSense too, but didn't work.

The specified behavior isn't ReSharper feature, but Visual Studio one - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/visual-studio-whole-line-completions.
